# The built-in VGG16 network in MxNet is not working

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

I would like to test the trained built-in VGG16 network in MxNet. The experiment is to feed the network with an image from ImageNet. Then, I would like to see whether the result is correct.

However, the results are always error! Hi, how stupid the network is! Well, that cannot be true. I must do something wrong.

```
from mxnet.gluon.model_zoo.vision import vgg16
from mxnet.image import color_normalize
import mxnet as mx
import numpy as np
import cv2
path=‘http://data.mxnet.io/models/imagenet-11k/’
data_dir = ‘F:/Temps/Models_tmp/’
k = ‘synset.txt’
#gluon.utils.download(path+k, data_dir+k)
img_dir = ‘F:/Temps/DataSets/ImageNet/’
img = cv2.imread(img_dir + ‘cat.jpg’)
img = mx.nd.array(img)
img,_ = mx.image.center_crop(img,(224,224))
img = img/255
img = color_normalize(img,mean=mx.nd.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406]),std=mx.nd.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225]))
img = mx.nd.transpose(img, axes=(2, 0, 1))
img = img.expand_dims(axis=0)
with open(data_dir + ‘synset.txt’, ‘r’) as f:
labels = [l.rstrip() for l in f]
aVGG = vgg16(pretrained=True,root=‘F:/Temps/Models_tmp/’)
features = aVGG.forward(img)
features = mx.ndarray.softmax(features)
features = features.asnumpy()
features = np.squeeze(features)
a = np.argsort(features)[::-1]
for i in a[0:5]:
  print(‘probability=%f, class=%s’ %(features[i], labels[i]))
```

The outputs from color_normalize seems not right for the absolute values of some numbers are greater than one.

This is my figure of cat which is downloaded from the ImageNet.

[image]

These are my outputs.

> probability=0.218258, class=n01519563 cassowary probability=0.172373,
>   class=n01519873 emu, Dromaius novaehollandiae, Emu novaehollandiae
>   probability=0.128973, class=n01521399 rhea, Rhea americana
>   probability=0.105253, class=n01518878 ostrich, Struthio camelus
>   probability=0.051424, class=n01517565 ratite, ratite bird, flightless
>   bird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your code:

`path=‘http://data.mxnet.io/models/imagenet-11k/’`

I think you might be using the synset of the ImageNet 11k (11000 classes) rather than the 1k (1000) classes. That would explain the mismatch.

The correct synset is here: http://data.mxnet.io/models/imagenet/synset.txt

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Another mistake that I have made is to import a BGR data rather than an RGB data. 

img = cv2.imread(img_dir + ‘cat.jpg’)

It should be

img = cv2.imread(img_dir + 'n01751748_838.JPEG')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

or

img = plt.imread(img_dir + 'n01751748_838.JPEG')

It would be better if there is something like ‘image.load_img’ as we do in keras. 

img = image.load_img(img_path + 'cat.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))

Comment: No problem, you can use `mx.image.imread` in mxnet to load an image as a NDArray directly.